# How to pass parameter to MSBuild from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

My issue is simple (or it is supposed to be so) 
I want to pass some parameter to MSBuild From Visual Studio, Not from the command line 
Put it in another way, How can I execute the following command when I click Build project from Visual Studio

`msbuild myproject.csproj -p:CustomParameter=ItsValue`

Thank you

Comment: many arguments (although not all) can be modified in the `All Options` section in the IDE, for example in VS2015:

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> All Options -> search for the switch/option you want.

Answer (score 8):

**On Visual Studio**, you only have to modify the `proj` file of the project. And this special and simple assignment is only a unique way of msbuild command line.

So you have to right-click on your project on the **Solution Explorer**-->**Unload Project**-->then right-click on the unload project-->**Edit Project File**,

add this at the bottom of the proj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>

<CustomParameter>ItsValue</CustomParameter>

</PropertyGroup>
```

**Every time** you want to change the custom value, you have to modify the property on the proj file.

This is the only way and actually, it is indeed not as convenient as the command line.

============================================

**Update 1**

**1)** add a new file called `test.props` file on the project folder

[image]

then add these content on the on the `test.props` file:

```
<Project>
<PropertyGroup>

<CustomParameter>ItsValue</CustomParameter>

</PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**2)** modify your `proj` file with this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <Import Project="test.props"/>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>


    <Target Name="test123" AfterTargets="Build">

        <Message Importance="high" Text="$(CustomParameter)"></Message>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

**3)** every time you should open `test.props` file, change the value of `CustomParameter`,save, click **Build** button, you will get what you want.

**So far**, this is by far the easiest way.

[image]

Comment: Actually, after I posted this question, I did that and it worked, but actually, I want to do that dynamically, I do not want to change the proj file every time I want to build. I am afraid that you are right, and there is no other way, unfortunately.

Comment: I have a better solution for you and hope it might do help for you. See `update 1`. And this is a easier way I found for you.

Comment: Yeah this will help to share the same parameter between multiple projects, but the main idea is the same, Thank you again for your help

Comment: Actually, the special feature is for msbuild command line and VS IDE did not have such convenient way. On VS IDE, you have to modify `csproj` at least once to get what you want. And my function is that modify once and then do not have to modify again. Split csproj file up into a separate props file so you have props file available for subsequent changes.

Comment: i will NOT accept this answer, please do not ask again for that. While your answer is working, it is not exactly what I was looking for. I upvoted your answer previously because it is helpful, but I will NOT accept it. Thank you again. Have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

If you have Visual Studio installed on a Windows PC, then:

1. Press keyboard Windows search key
2. Type `Developer Command Prompt for VS`
3. Open command prompt
4. Type `msbuild <path to your .sln or .csproj file> <optional: switches>`. e.g. `msbuild c:/source/AcmeInc/AcmeInc.sln /p:Configuration=Release`